# List all 'feeds' and only 2 users with relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to make a list of all the items in the table `feed` and show only the first 2 users who subscribe to the content, but I can not put together a query that does the list only 2 users `limit 2`.

I've tried *N* querys and *subquery*, but could not get the expected result. The nearest was using `group_concat`, but if it concatenates *all* users and does not allow limited only to two initial, and would have to use`substring_index` for this purpose.

<sub>**Query**</sub>

```
select
  feed.id
, feed.type
, user.name

 from feed
 inner join user on user.id = feed.user
 group by feed.type
```

---

<sub>**Result**</sub>

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [id] => 1
            [type] => Comedy
            [name] => Mike
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [id] => 3
            [type] => War
            [name] => John
        )

    [2] => Array(
            [id] => 6
            [type] => Terror
            [name] => Sophia
        )
)
```

---

<sub>**Expected**</sub>

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [id] => 1
            [type] => Comedy
            [name] => Mike, Papa
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [id] => 3
            [type] => War
            [name] => John, Alex
        )

    [2] => Array(
            [id] => 6
            [type] => Terror
            [name] => Sophia, Jessica
        )
)
```

Comment: You need to limit your result set, this is a [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @rn=0;
select id, type, name 
from 
(
select 
@rn:=@rn+1 AS r_n
,feed.id
,feed.type
,user.name
from feed
inner join user on user.id = feed.user
group by feed.id
order by feed.id) t
where t.r_n <= 2
```

You can generate row numbers per group and then select the first 2 rows per feed id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to simulate `row_number()` to give each user per feed a "rank" and only select rows with number <= 2 before doing the grouping in order to only get 2 users per group:

```
select id, type, group_concat(name) from (
    select * from (
        select *, @rn := if(@prevFeedId = id, @rn+1, 1) as rn,
        @prevFeedId := id
        from (
            select
            feed.id
            , feed.type
            , user.name
            from feed
            inner join user on user.id = feed.user
        ) t1 order by id
    ) t1 where rn <= 2
) t1 group by id, type
```

Comment: thank you, there was an error: `Unknown column 'rn' in 'where clause' `

Comment: Not yet, `group by id, type` not grouped, so I used `group by type` but it seems that `where rn <= 2` not work, appears a list of all users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the schema of your tables but try the same approach you already tried with group_concat but join to a subquery like:

```
...
inner join 
(
  select user.id, user.name from user limit 2
) as x on x.id = feed.user
...
```

Comment: When I use `limit 2`, list 2 feeds; `limit 3` list 3 feeds. Not limited only to users.